# Why isn't session value persisting after redirect?

Tags: python, django, session, django-rest-framework, backend

thank you for your time and attention to this query.

I am trying to set (key, value) into the request session from one drf function and accessing that (key, value) via the request session in another drf function. Please see the code below for the current implmentation:

```
class FunctionOne(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = []

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.session["kcc"] = request.GET.get("code")
        request.session.modified = True
        print("kcc", request.session.get("kcc", None))
        return redirect("http://localhost:3000/checkout")

class FunctionTwo(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = []

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(dir(request.session))
        code = request.session.get("kcc")

        if code:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

It is successfully setting the (key, value) into the session in function one and can be seen via the print statement. However when accessing the function two view the (key, value) saved in the session can't be found. I've checked the settings.py `"django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware"` is included in the middleware and also these are the current rest_framework settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "backend.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ],
}
```

Additionally, I am not using the default Sqlite database that is shipped with Django, I have a postgresql database hooked up to the project instead. I would greatly appreciate if pointed in the right direction to solve this issue and/or getting this issue solved in this thread. Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Upon additional testing via print statements I found that the session_key for function one has a value, but when accessing function two the value of the session_key becomes None.

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: Can you try to set a test cookie in your first function and test if the cookie worked in the second function? ...like described in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#s-setting-test-cookies

Comment: @Geilmaker We tested via print statements and protocols initiated from the client side. I was able to fix the problem, since the redirect was happening from an external domain, the session cookie was being set for that domain, and not on the client side connected to this server. The fix to the problem was to redirect back to the server from the external domain through a call back function, and then redirect back to the client, in turn the session cookie was set successfully where the client can communicate with the server.

Comment: @aaron Thank you as well for stepping into help, please see above for the solution explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below for the solution to this problem:

Function one triggered from external domain.

```
class FunctionOne(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = []

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        code = request.GET.get("code")
        server_domain = os.environ.get("SERVER_DOMAIN")
        response = HttpResponseRedirect(
            f"{server_domain}/callback/?value={code}"
        )
        return response
```

Now the callback function view:

```
def CallBack(request):
    client_domain = os.environ.get("CLIENT_DOMAIN")
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(f"{client_domain}/checkout")
    cookie_value = request.GET.get("value")

    # Set the cookie in the response headers
    # This is to set in development.
    response.set_cookie("kcc", cookie_value)
    
    # This is to set in production.
    response.set_cookie(
        "kcc", cookie_value, domain="example.com", secure=True, samesite="None"
    )

    return response
```

By doing so, Function Two can now access the (key, value) in the session:

```
class FunctionTwo(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = []

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        code = request.session.get("kcc")

        if code:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).